# block Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: java, mysql, angular, spring, spring-mvc

Access to XMLHttpRequest at
 'http://localhost:8080/SpringVendor/login/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200'
 has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

It may seem like a known issue and many questions exist on the topic. However, my situation is very strange.
 I have a simple web application that is deployed on tomcat 8.5.45 and I have configured the CORS properly:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This is controller
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value = Constants.REQ_MAP_LOGIN, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String vendorloginMethodPost(@RequestBody VendorLogin vendoridlogin) {

```
    System.out.println(vendoridlogin);

    String message = Constants.EMPTY_STRING;
    String id = dao.getLoginDetails(vendoridlogin);

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    if (id == null) {
        message = "login fail";

    } else {
        message = " login Successfully";
    }

    String json = gson.toJson(message);
    return json; 
}
```

This is doaImplementation

@Override
    public String getLoginDetails(VendorLogin vendorlogin) {

```
    String getVendorData = "select vendor_ID  from vendor_login where vendor_ID='" + vendorlogin.getVendorLoginId()
            + "' and password= '" + vendorlogin.getPassWord() + "' and type_of_vendor='" + vendorlogin.getTypeOfVendor()+ "'";
    String name = null;
    try {

        name = (String) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(getVendorData, String.class);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Database operation for a query:" + getVendorData + "Failed Details Message:"
                + e.getLocalizedMessage() + " ");
    }
    return name;

}
```

i am working on webservices..frontend is an angular and backend i am using java spring..

Comment: please allow CORS request from backend https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/webmvc/spring-mvc-cors-configuration/.

Comment: you can either do what @SantoshShinde said or just add a proxy in your app